# Uploading big files with cy.fixture()

Tags: cypress

Is there any limitations regarding the file size cy.fixture() can handle? I'm trying to load a 100MB file and constantly get

`cy.fixture() timed out waiting 600000ms to receive a fixture. No fixture was ever sent by the server.`

Increasing the timeout doesn't help as you can see.

Comment: Hi angryorangutan. `cy.fixture()` handles lightly this kind of size. The error says something different than size limitation and is hard to understand why it happens. If you could add more details like, code snippet you call for fixture command, or some more console logs would be more helpful to understand the root cause